# Angular template check returns error Object is possibly null

Tags: angular, typescript

I have below is in my TS file

```
export class MatCarouselComponent {
 
  @Input() public svgIconOverrides: SvgIconOverrides | null = null;
  ...
}
```

In my html file I have

```html
    <mat-icon
      *ngIf="svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward; else: defaultArrowForward"
      [svgIcon]="svgIconOverrides.arrowForward"
    ></mat-icon>
```

So basically I would expect that when the value of `svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward` is Falsy then the component `mat-icon` will not be shown and `defaultArrowForward` will be shown.

Simply by the time we reach `[svgIcon]="svgIconOverrides.arrowForward"`, the value of `svgIconOverrides` cannot be of type `null`. Unfortunately if I try to compile I receive error which I dont get why.

```
Error: src/app/mat-carousel/mat-carousel.component.html:59:35 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

59       [svgIcon]="svgIconOverrides.arrowForward"
```

Now If I try using null check `[svgIcon]="svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward"` I receive error

```
Error: src/app/mat-carousel/mat-carousel.component.html:59:8 - error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

59       [svgIcon]="svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward"
```

Finally my solution to the problem is to use `??` [svgIcon]="svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward ?? ''" which does not make sence to me, why do I need to add the condition to expression that I believe will never be called? Or is it that I am missing something?

Comment: Well probably `mat-icon` has an input type like `@Input svgIcon:string` so you have to pass a string. Whereas your `svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward` might be undefined.

Comment: Have you tried putting in svgIconOverrides model an exclamation after the arrowForward? Like this: arrowForward!: string

Comment: @eko I understand that part, the issue I don't get is why typescript is not recognising that  using `*ngIf` will ensure that the value is not null

Comment: You can try `*ngIf="!!svgIconOverrides?.arrowForward; else ...`

Comment: You need to have `"strictNullChecks": true` set in your `tsconfig.json` according to this https://indepth.dev/posts/1123/type-checking-templates-in-angular-viewengine-and-ivy#type-guard-for-ngif